# Youtube embed video endless loading in old browser

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using Youtube iframe embed code in my project but it doesn't work correctly just showing a looping circle. Here its `iframe` code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is my client's user-agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36 SRAF/4.0
```

I can't ask my client to update since it's an embedded tv browser. It's working fine on updated browser in another computer. Any solutions please?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: @Titulum which code? I just edited the question.

Comment: The `iframe` code, thank you.